# datediff function for FQL, or other way to easily get event duration?

Tags: facebook-fql

I want to return the event durations from this single facebook FQL query. Is there something like the SQL datediff function that I can use?

```
SELECT eid, name, start_time, end_time FROM event WHERE eid IN ( SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me() ) ORDER BY start_time ASC
```

Comment: No, there isn’t. (FQL is not even close to a full-fledged “SQL” dialect, it knows very few functions.) You’ll have to do that in your processing of the data afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is definitely to post process as CBroe mentioned.

Here is an incomplete way to do this in FQL

`SELECT start_time, end_time, strtotime(lower(end_time)) - strtotime(lower(start_time)) FROM event WHERE eid IN ( SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me() ) AND strlen(end_time) > 0`

And a sample response

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "start_time": "2015-03-14T21:00:00-0400", 
      "end_time": "2015-03-15T03:00:00-0400", 
      "anon": 21600
    }, 
    {
      "start_time": "2015-02-16T21:00:00-0400", 
      "end_time": "2015-02-17T02:00:00-0400", 
      "anon": 18000
    }, 
    {
      "start_time": "2015-01-30T22:00:00-0400", 
      "end_time": "2015-01-31T08:00:00-0400", 
      "anon": 36000
    }, 
    {
      "start_time": "2015-01-24T18:00:00-0400", 
      "end_time": "2015-01-25T00:00:00-0400", 
      "anon": 21600
    }, 
    {
      "start_time": "2015-01-09T22:00:00-0400", 
      "end_time": "2015-01-10T04:00:00-0400", 
      "anon": 21600
    }, 
    {
      "start_time": "2015-01-02T22:00:00-0400", 
      "end_time": "2015-01-03T04:00:00-0400", 
      "anon": 21600
    }
  ]
}
```

The anon field is returned in seconds so

- 21600 = 6 hours
- 18000 = 5 hours
- 36000 = 10 hours

Which correctly match the difference in start and end times above.